# Rails: Redirecting from one controller action to another (non-GET)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, put

I have a GET route which, before rendering the view, the Controller checks for an optional param. If it's there, I'd like to bypass rendering the view and "redirect" straight to another controller action. The other action is a PUT route and I realize we can't simply redirect to PUT routes as you could to a GET route.

This is roughly what I've attempted so far but I don't know how to invoke the redirect, as it's impossible with PUT. Perhaps there's some different design pattern for handling this sort of behavior? Thanks in advance.

```
Controller actions:

def foo      
  if 'XYZ'
    # "redirect" to bar
  else
    render 'view'
  end
end

#bar is a PUT route
def bar 
  ...
end
```

Comment: something smells fishy here. Why would you like to redirect a PUT request to be handled somewhere else? maybe you need to change your route instead

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky Hm, that could work. I wanted to retain the original PUT route because it's used by another part of the app. It may not be DRY but you think it would be best to add the code from the PUT route to foo under the if XYZ line?

Comment: if you're using the RESTful rails architecture, the PUT request should update an object (or entity). If that's not the case, maybe you can extract anothet Form Object. try reading [here](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to use the `bar` method given the condition being met

```
def foo      
  if 'XYZ'
    bar
  else
    render 'view'
  end
end
```

This would run the `bar` method and make use of any redirect you have in there. It is more likely that you want to reexamine what it is you are trying to achieve.

If you can give more specifics then you will get a better answer.

Comment: For some reason it hadn't occurred to me that you could simply call the route like a ruby object. Thanks.

To clarify, the PUT is still making updates to a resource, then it renders a view afterwards. I simply just wanted to bypass the default view rendering behavior given the conditional being met. Sorry if that wasn't clear in OP

Answer (score 0):

If you have your routes for `bar` action something like this

```
match '/controller/bar/' => 'controller#bar'
```

modify it like

```
match '/controller/bar/' => 'controller#bar' , :via => [:get,:post,:put]
```